# JFXDatePicker not appearing in Scene Builder with JFoenix 9.0.10 and Scene Builder 19.0.0 (Java 20), despite other components working

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, jfoenix

"I'm using JFoenix 9.0.10 and Scene Builder 19.0.0 for a Java project, but the JFXDatePicker component is not showing up in Scene Builder's search bar. I've already imported the JFoenix library and refreshed the component list, but to no avail. Other JFoenix components are working properly. I'm using the latest version of Java. How can I fix this issue?"

Accompanied by these two screenshots:

[Screenshot of Scene Builder with the missing JFXDatePicker component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6rJX.png)
[Screenshot of the import section with the imported JFoenix library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4LVe.png)

Comment: From the posts on this site, there are unresolved issues with JFoenix.  I advise MaterialFX instead.